# Posting on https url of webservices

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to post some data on https url there is no certificate for that url because that are only webservices my code is given below

```
DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();   
ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();
String   sourceURL=context.getResources().getString(R.string.web_service_url)+"/authenticateUser";
    Log.d("INSIDE AUTHENTICATION", "URLSOFAuthenticateuser" +sourceURL);
    HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(sourceURL);   
    List<NameValuePair> userDetails = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    userDetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId)); 
    userDetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userPass", userPass)); 

    try {

        Log.d("inside", "&*&*&*&*"+userDetails);
        postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(userDetails)); 
        Log.d("iNSIDE 1", "&*&*&*"+hc.execute(postMethod,res));
        response=hc.execute(postMethod,res);
        Log.d("iNSIDE 2", "&*&*&*");



    }
    catch(HttpResponseException g)
    {
        Log.d("", "&*&*&*HttpResponseException");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.d("", "&*&*&*UnsupportedEncodingException");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("", "&*&*&*ClientProtocolException");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("", "&*&*&*IOException");

    }  
       return response;
```

could you please help me regarding the problem.Is there any way to make an httppost on https urls.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

This should help..let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: Actually in given example he is accepting some particular keystore from raw folder i want to accept all untrusted certificate.